# Stick footer on bottom of web page

Tags: html, css, position, footer

I want my footer to be always on the bottom of the page, even when the content is very short.
I have checked this one http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page but does not work.

My HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrap-footer">
      <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

My CSS:

```
 #footer { 
   height: 320px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

With this one, when I have a short content is ok, but when I have a long one the footer goes in the middle of the page and stuck there.
Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `position: fixed` is the correct answer, but be aware that browser support for this is far from universal. In the past I've had to use something javascript-based to keep my footer in the right place. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/mobile.html for more details on browser support.

Comment: position fixed, make the footer stick on the end on the page, but not where the content ends. so is not what I want

Comment: @Dan From my understanding, he wants it at the bottom of the document, not the browser.

Comment: Just realised that's what I get for skimming through a question - my apologies..

Comment: @jumpingcode How is that different from what happens if you don't have a `position` at all and let the browser layout divs as normal?

Comment: @novellino I think I've the solution

Comment: This question has been asked before. A lot. The simplest solution that I always end up using can be found here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. Bear in mind, this is pretty much impossible without fixing the height of your footer (until `position: sticky` is a reality).

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials on the web that show exactly this.

Comment: I used this one http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ at the end and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:fixed;` to your footer it should work

```
#footer { 
   height: 320px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:fixed` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/akMpT/

If you're just looking to push the footer down to the bottom of the page (as jumpingcode suggests), without fixing its position. Set the container height to 100%, and also any parent elements including `<html>` and `<body>`

Fiddle for the height:100% method: http://jsfiddle.net/akMpT/1/

As pointed out in the comments my second method isn't perfect. This subject has been tackled a hundred times, here's one example of how to do it correctly with CSS. Google has countless others. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: This is a sticky footer, not a footer at the bottom of the document.

Comment: The question is: Stick footer on bottom of web page.

Comment: @logic-unit I think he means he wants the footer always on at the bottom of the page. E.g: If the content is 100px in height the footer would still be all the way at the bottom of the page and not just sitting under the 100px content part. ( I think )

Comment: yes exactly. position fixed is not what i want

Comment: @logic-unit Update your fiddle to show it works and I will +1

Comment: @logic-unit and +1 Good job.

Comment: Your second fiddle does not work if document height is less than content height. Which OP mentions he wants.

Comment: It also doesn't work if document height is greater than 100% + footer height: http://jsfiddle.net/akMpT/2/

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's because you are applying the positioning to the wrong element.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/hDfFL/)

```
#wrap-footer { 
   height: 320px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
    background:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> providing "position:fixed" will keep your footer on the bottom or anywhere you like to keep it with additional properties (top:0;bottom:0;,left:0;,right:0;). Use them with "position property".

```
 #wrap-footer
{
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   bottom: 0;
   height:10px; /*according to your will*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sticky Footer (Bottom of Browser)

***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wsyMA/2/)***

**CSS**

```
footer { position:fixed; bottom:0px; }$(document).ready(function() {
```

### Normal Footer (Bottom of Document)

***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wsyMA/1/)***

**CSS**

```
footer { bottom:0px; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    moveFooter();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        moveFooter();
    });

    function moveFooter() {
        var dH = $(document).height();
        var wH = $(window).height();

        if (dH < wH)
            $('footer').css("position", "relative");
        else
            $('footer').css("position", "absolute");
    }
});
```

Comment: I feel using jQuery is a bit much but still its works. +1 Good job.

Comment: @Ruddy It's really difficult without jQuery for older browsers.

Comment: Javascript is overkill for the problem even in older browsers.

Comment: @logic-unit How would you propose to implement a non-sticky footer? Yours does not work if document height is less than window height or if window height and footer height are less than document height?

Comment: @logic-unit And you've pathetically downvoted because I pointed out flaws in your solution?

Comment: Downvote as OP doesn't ask for Javascript.

Comment: @logic-unit Oh dear...

Comment: So you've just gone round my previous answers to other questions and downvoted them? You've taken that downvote badly. Pretty sad.

Comment: What the? I haven't downvoted anything, not even your answer to this question.